# Do we take Birth with Physical Body in Hell/Heaven?

Tags: karma, atma, lokas, gods

**EXPLANATION :**

- People living in Heaven have **Childhood** and also **Marry and Fight with Humans**,Vanaras,etc,.this clears that they have **Physical Body**.
- I didn't know whether we take **Birth in Hell/Heaven** as like Humans or Different Manner.

**QUESTION :**

- Do we take Birth with Physical Body in Hell/Heaven ?
- If yes then do we have **Childhood in Hell**  ?

Comment: God (Deva) like Indra, sun, wind ect also has body but that body is more evolved than human body. Those body are knows as divine body (Daiviya Shareer) which we can't even see by our week eyes (our eyes don't have enough power to see it). When someone died then He/she also gets that kind of divine body to stay in heaven. Because we can't enter in heaven with our current body, so we have to enter in new body to stay in heaven. New body is necessary for both heaven and hell.

Comment: @Rishabh friend then how devas were seen and battled by ignorant asuras

Comment: Asura has same divine body which Devas has. May be you don't know that Devas and Asuras both are children of same father named as [Rishi Kashyap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashyapa) who is the [Saptarishi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saptarishi). All Saptarishi were created by Lord Brahma himself and they all has Divine bodies. Rishi Kashyap also has Divine body and this is the reason all Devas and Asuras has Divine bodies coz they got that body from there parents. Moreover it's true we can't see them but still they can appear in front of us if they wish to.

Comment: @Rishabh Friend then in all yugas were Normal people didn't see any asuras

Comment: Asuras are little different case on that point Because Devas are use to worship by humans, so it is not like that you can see any devas routing around. Or may be I am wrong on that point, We may see.

Comment: @Rishabh Yes friend both of us are not clear we must wait for someone to clear the confusion